# Why is the index of a harmonic map finite?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, vector-bundles, elliptic-operators

Let $M,N$ be compact Riemannian manifolds, and let $\phi:M \to N$ be harmonic.

The **index** of $\phi$ is defined to be the dimension of the maximal subspaces of $\Gamma(\phi^*TN)$ on which the hessian of the Dirichlet energy is negative definite.

Why is it true that the index is always finite?

Does it follow from the ellipticity of the Jacobi operator?

I know that the hessian of the Dirichlet energy is given by
$$
H(E)_{\phi}(V,V)= \int_{M} \langle J_{\phi}(V),V \rangle \text{Vol}_g   
$$
where $J:\Gamma(\phi^*TN) \to \Gamma(\phi^*TN))$ is the **Jacobi operator**, i.e.

$$ J_{\phi}(V)=-\text{trace}_{g} R^{TN}(V,d\phi(\cdot))d\phi(\cdot)+\nabla^*\nabla V.
 $$